# "Unflatten" a yaml file

Tags: bash, yaml

I am looking for a Bash tool/script (or basically anything that I can easily execute in a shell) which can help me "unflatten" a YAML file. What I mean by "unflatten" is the following:

Let's say I have a file that looks like this:

```
a.b.c: "foo"
a.b.d: "bar"
a.e: "baz"
a.f.g: "qux"
...
```

I want to convert it to a proper YAML file with the appropriate indentation like so:

```
a:
  b:
    c: "foo"
    d: "bar"
  e: "baz"
  f:
    g: "qux:
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've not foud any simple way to do that with `bash`. You could use a 3rd party library like https://github.com/Codearte/props2yaml to achieve what you want (several tools exist, I'll let you google and pick the one most suited to your needs)

Comment: Note well that the two YAML snippets you present are not equivalent as far as YAML is concerned.  If they mean the same thing to some application then that's application-specific.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install yq from https://github.com/mikefarah/yq, then:

```
yq eval "$(awk -F ": " '{print s"."$1"="$2;s="|"}' your-file)" /dev/null
```